# how to avoid poilymophic call in base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a class in which some methods call other methods like in the following example:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "base::foo" << endl;
        bar();
    }
    virtual void bar() {
        cout << "base::bar" << endl;
    }
};
```

Then I want to make a wrapper class in which each method calls the base class method and some additional stuff that I use for some tests.

```
class Derived :public Base {
public:
    void foo() override {
        cout << "derived::foo" << endl;
        Base::foo();
    } 
    void bar() override {
        cout << "derived::bar" << endl;
        Base::bar();
    }
};
```

My program was calling functions from Base class and I've changed it to call from Derived class.

```
int main() {
    //Base A;
    Derived A;
    A.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

In the above example when I call Derived::foo(), it calls Base::foo(), which in turn calls bar(); Due to polymorphism, when bar() is called from Base::foo(), it is resolved to Derived::bar(). I would like that Base::foo() to call Base::bar() and only the calls from Derived to call Base methods. Is it possible to achieve this without modifying the base class?

Comment: No, it is not possible without modifying some aspect of the base class.   You can modify `Base::foo()` so it explicitly calls `Base::bar()` and also `Derived::bar()` so it explicitly calls `Derived::foo()`.    A need to avoid virtual function calls does suggest a design problem - if you don't want virtual function calls, why are the functions virtual?

Comment: @Peter, actually in the real world situation Base inherits from an abstract class that's why the methods are virtual.

Comment: That doesn't change my point.   You're inheriting from an abstract base so that derived classes can (or must, if they are pure) override functions they inherit.  The fact you're looking to change things to avoid calls to the derived versions says you have a design problem.   You're essentially trying to work around deficiencies in your own design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use static dispatch to a virtual function by qualifying the name of the function:

```
virtual void foo() {
    cout << "base::foo" << endl;
    Base::bar();
}
```

> Is it possible to achieve this without modifying the base class?

I don't think so; at least not if you count modifying the definition of the member functions of the base class.